# I'm unsure why the newline character isn't affecting what's printed

Tags: java, eclipse, newline, filewriter

I am writing a simple program to keep track of my fuel consumption. I am trying to figure out why the newline character is not outputting
to the file, but the other fields are.

```
PrintWriter fuelLog = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("FuelLog.txt", true));
fuelLog.println("New Trip");
miles = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter trip miles...");
dollars = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter cost to refuel...");
gallons = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the gallons used on the trip...");

fuelLog.println("Miles on trip: " + miles + "\n" + 
                "Cost: $" + dollars + "\n" + 
                "Gallons used: " + gallons);
fuelLog.close();
```

The output to my file ends up being something like this for example:

> Miles on trip: 270.67Cost: $33.76Gallons used: 11.567

The desired output to the file I am looking for is:

> Miles on trip: 270.67
>   Cost: $33.76
>   Gallons used: 11.567

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The newline character(s) is (are) platform dependent, and may very well be `\r\n` on your platform. You can avoid the problem by using `printf` with the `%n` special character that gets translated to the proper newline in your platform. As a side effect, it can also help clean up your code and avoid all those string concatinations:

```
fuelLog.printf("Miles on trip: %s%n" + 
               "Cost: $%s%n" + 
               "Gallons used: %s%n", miles, dollars, gallons);
```

Comment: Okay. Your method solved the issue I had. I have a question about the %s character though. Does that character take the strings that I have and insert them? I'm unclear on that specific character.

Comment: @RyanEdwards yes, indeed - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax for details